# Magento 2 : CSS not including in custom theme

Tags: magento, layout, magento2

I have a custom theme developed on vanilla magento 2.1.5 which is working as expected. I already have a magento 1.9 site and I migrated that DB and connected to 2.1.5. When I connect that migrated database to to the 2.1.5 codebase, the CSS I made for the custome theme is not getting included. This is my default_head_blocks.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <css src="css/source/custom/common.css"/>
        <css src="css/source/custom/font-awesome.css"/>
        <script src="requirejs/require.js"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Components" name="head.components" as="components" template="Magento_Theme::js/components.phtml" before="-"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

I have given 0 value in theme table in database. The css file is generating as expected in pub/static folder. How to include that css file in my custom theme

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue, but haven't been able to determine the root cause yet. As far as I can tell it's an issue when a theme is extending a theme that isn't the Magento/blank.